# Rcpp - transform NumericVector with binary function?

Tags: c++, rcpp

I'm looking at speeding up some R code by re-writing in C++ & integrating via Rcpp.  My Cpp is, to say the least, rusty: so would appreciate any suggestions.  In particular, I'm looking for pointers on mapping a function onto all elements of an Rcpp `NumericVector`.  Here's an example.

I need to produce a new vector as follows:

- Take a `tail` slice of an existing `NumericVector`;
- divide through each element of the new slice by a divisor

I have this so far:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cppAdjustProbabilities(  NumericVector& currentProbs, 
                                       const int index,
                                       const double divisor ) {

  //Note index <=0, e.g. -1 means remove first element
  if(index == 0) {
    return(currentProbs);
  } else {
    NumericVector newProbs = no_init(currentProbs.size()+index);                 
    NumericVector::iterator i = currentProbs.begin() - index; 
    NumericVector::iterator j = newProbs.begin();
    for(; i != currentProbs.end(); ++i, ++j) {
      *j=*i/divisor;
    }    
    return(newProbs);
  }
}
```

This works, but I'd prefer to use a "map" approach.  I looked at `std::transform`, but it only supports a unary operation on vector elements - so I can't see how to pass the divisor in.  This, for example, isn't valid:

```
std::transform(currentProbs.begin()-index, currentProbs.end(),
               newProbs.begin(), [](double val) { return (val / divisor);} );
```

Is there a way to bring the `divisor` into scope in the lambda? Or another way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: So that I understand, you want to divide each element of the slice by a value? For example, if `currentProbs` was (0.1, 0.2, 0.3), index was -1 and divisor was 2, would the output be (0.1, 0.15) -- take every element but the first, (0.2, 0.3), and divide by two to get (0.1, 0.15)?

Comment: I ask because I highly doubt dividing a subset of a vector is a context you'll get much (if any) speed gains vs. R

Comment: @duckmayr, yes that's correct -thanks.  This is just part of a much larger calculation, hence reason for investigating.  Also looking at whether linking in an alternative BLAS library will improve things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [c++ lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) you can capture a value like this:

```
src1 <- 'NumericVector cppAdjustProbabilities(  NumericVector& currentProbs, 
                                       const int index,
                                       const double divisor ) {

  //Note index <=0, e.g. -1 means remove first element
  if(index == 0) {
    return(currentProbs);
  } else {
    NumericVector newProbs = no_init(currentProbs.size()+index);
    std::transform(currentProbs.begin()-index, currentProbs.end(),
               newProbs.begin(), [&divisor](double val) { return (val / divisor);} );
               //                 ^^^^^^^^
    return(newProbs);
  }
}'

Rcpp::cppFunction(src1)

currentProbs <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)
index <- -5L
divisor <- 2.0
cppAdjustProbabilities(currentProbs, index, divisor)
#> [1] 0.30 0.35 0.40 0.45
```

Comment: Thanks @Ralf Stubner, that's great.